# What should i use for a Remote Desktop Control?

Tags: python, twisted, python-imaging-library

Hi everybody i'm new to stackoverflow and to python programming :-)

Can somebody point me in the right direction or suggest me a good way to do this..?

The software I'd like to write is a kind of "multiple remote control", it has:

- **One Server**  ... whose task is to send his screen to all the clients
- **Many Clients** ... they show the Server's screen and they are all able to control it (there exist a lot of remote control applications which can do this,but not all the clients together i think .. practically one server with many mice :p .. however all the clients will be managed by the server)

Given that I'm new to python i started looking and using these libraries:

**wxWidget** for the gui

**Twisted** for the network connection, because it's an easy way to implement a multicast UDP .. but is udp the right choise to send images to all the clients? =/

**PIL** (Python Imaging Libary) images stuff and to grab the screenshots on the Server machine to send to the clients .. this is the point where I stopped to think to all the possible solutions ... (I wasn't able to send the image to the client, I tried converting it to string but the UDP message was not that big :) )

I've seen many suggest the use of a VNC application .. is it easy to develop my software as described around it (actually i have no idea how..), or grabbing the screen continuously with PIL and sending somehow the images to the clients is an acceptable solution?

Thanks in advance for any help :-)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [VNC viewer implemented in Python](http://homepage.hispeed.ch/py430/python/).

Answer (score 2):

[Teamtalk](http://www.teamtalk.im/) is a Python IM software that also has Remote Desktop access. You can download the source and look at the implementation.

Comment: Thanks i'm having a look right now and i see that they use vnc, there's a lot of stuff that I actually dont understand in those sources but I'll keep trying :)

Comment: I think the link to Teamtalk may have changed. Is there a way I can get the source of this or something similar.